# Content is displayed under admin bar

Tags: admin, admin-bar

After updating to 3.4, my admin bar is not pushing down the content in the admin area.

In this picture I have scrolled right up to the top of the page:

[greedy admin bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGw7u.png)

The problem is that notices get hidden under it.

I've tried network deactivating all plugins, but no luck!

I COULD just edit the core #adminmenu and #wpbody css to have a top margin of 28px, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

Anybody come across this before?

Comment: Not being picky with you, but maybe this Stack should have a huge link to this article: [Troubleshooting WordPress 3.4 - Master List](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list)...

Comment: @brasofilo
That's probably not a bad idea ;)
I tried everything on that list of steps except manually upgrading, so of course that was the solution. Deleting the wp-admin folder and uploading a fresh copy of it solved my problem. I do not recall editing any code in that folder, but I may have done so a few months ago before I knew the trouble I could get into with editing back-end code.

Answer (score 1):

Some themes and plugins change the style of Admin Dashboard. Try changing the theme also once. 
It is more likely that a theme or plugin caused the issue rather than changes in WordPress back end code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried that, as well as disabling all plug-ins, but it didn't work. I ended up just installing a fresh copy of my wp-admin folder and it solved the issue. I must have mucked around with code that I shouldn't have.